# Get JSON data from request body on .NET Core Web API within ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, action-filter, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing a custom ActionFilterAttribute in order to handle some business logic before the request hits the action in .Net Core Web API. (Core v1.1)
The handler is being successfully hit by OnActionExecuting, but I am not able to extract its data sent in JSON format that is coming from the request body.

I have tried in few ways, like reading the ActionExecutingContext stream body (which comes empty), accesing the Form property (but as it is json, it does not work), and some other solutions but no luck on that.

This is the code for my ActionFilter, which is empty, since the issue here is basically the need to extract its data, so further code would be irrelevant.

```
public class AccountRestrictionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
     public override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
     {      
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer credit goes to rynowak, I found it here https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5260

ModelBinding runs before action filters so if you have form data or a [FromBody] parameter, we've already read it.

Yes, if you're inside an action filter then context.ActionArguments will contain all of the model objects we created. So if you have:

```
public IActionResult Edit(int id, [FromBody] Widget widget) { }
```

Then context.ActionArguments["widget"] will return the Widget object. If you're trying to do this in a generic way, look at context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters - this will contain all of the parameter definitions and metadata.

Comment: Not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the request body inside an action filter you need to use a `StreamReader` and enable buffering as in the example below...

```
public class AccountRestrictionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var body = string.Empty;
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        request.EnableBuffering();
        if(request.Body.CanSeek) request.Body.Position = 0;

        using (var s = new StreamReader(request.Body, encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
            detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            body = s.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body);
        //account restriction logic below
    }
}
```

I'm leaving the stream open just in case you want to do further processing in a different middleware such as logging. Here's an example of the following JSON sent in a request...

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "email": "user@contoso.com",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "role": "Admin"
}
```

and a debugging screenshot with a breakpoint in VS...

[image]

Don't forget annotate the action method with the action filter...

```
    [HttpPost(""), AccountRestriction]
    public IResult RestrictedArea()
    {
        ...
    }
```

You can even pass arguments to the action filter...

```
    [HttpPost(""), AccountRestriction(AllowedRoles = "Admin,Supervisor")]
    public IResult RestrictedArea()
    {
        ...
    }
```

And then process the arguments passed in...

```
public class AccountRestrictionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string AllowedRoles { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //code ommitted for better clarity...

        var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountModel>(body);
        var roles = AllowedRoles.Split(',', options: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (roles.Contains(account.Role.ToString()))
        {
            var allowedRoles = context.ActionArguments[AllowedRoles];    
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

### IMPORTANT!!!

Do not use this for access control or or authorization purposes. The recommended way to authorize requests is through access tokens.